# What value are these resistors?

Tags: power-supply, identification

These are two resistors that were in series with a transformer on the mains (120 V AC) input of an audio amplifier power supply. The PCB under them has become discolored with heat after being in service for 22 years. I removed them from the board and measured them. Surprisingly, they are both 2.81 kΩ, but the color bands would suggest 10 kΩ ±10%.

I am surprised that they measure much less than expected. Further, I wouldn't expect the measured resistance to be so similar to each other if indeed they have failed over time (2.815 k and 2.813 k).

Either I have interpreted the color band incorrectly, or they have managed to degrade very similarly to an out-of-spec resistance.

They measure 11 x 5 mm which I think may be rated for 1 W but I am not sure. The color bands are faded.

**What value would seem reasonable for these resistors?** I don't know what purpose they serve in a linear power supply where they are between fuse and transformer (current-limiting? soft start?).

Here is a partial schematic. There is a TRIAC and opto-isolator after the resistors in question (R1, R2).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD85gM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And here is a picture of the resistors:

[image: Power resistors]

**Edit:**

I updated the schematic after one of the answers indicated that I had not sufficiently probed the board to see that the TRIAC is in parallel with the resistors.

Comment: That could be orange,black,red.  Which would be 3k.

Comment: Did you pull the via barrel out? The upper left lead looks suspicious.

Comment: Given that there's a fuse in series, I would expect a resistance in the single-digit Ohms range. What's the output voltage of the transformer and what's the rating of the fuse?

Comment: @qrk Yes, I will have to repair the PCB when replacing that one.

Comment: @JonathanS. sorry I omitted those details! The transformer is 59V 150VA with center tap. The fuse is 1.8A (250V).

Comment: @HandyHowie Interesting, I hadn't considered that option. If they started out as 3k and have degraded to 2.8k, that could explain why the fuse keeps blowing.

Comment: I would have expected them to be brown-black-brown, ie 100 Ohm. That is typical to reduce the current surge at switch-on and prevent the fuse from blowing. But both  2.81k? No wonder the board got hot! Are the tolerance bands silver? That would rule out 3k0 and mean they have overcooked coincidentally the same amount; in this unlikely situation, I'd check my ohmmeter against a known good resistor to be sure.

Comment: At 10% they would still be in spec.  Is there anything else connected to that fuse?

Comment: @HandyHowie No, the hot enters the board, immediately through the fuse, then into the resistors. From the resistors there's a split to both the transformer primary and the TRIAC. The TRIAC (MT2) or the side opposite mains goes through a small resistor and to the opto-isolator and nowhere else. (There is a non-populated part on the board.)

Comment: @Guy I considered that perhaps the resistors are supposed to be brown-black-pink which would make them 10mΩ but that seems far too low to be useful for switch-on limiting, but maybe not. I expect resistors like these to fail open or short; other failure modes I'm unsure about (and I'm not even sure they have failed--they just seem to have cooked the board near them).

Comment: Hmm I'm betting they are 100Ω as well. Disconnect the secondary of the transformer and see if the fuse still pops - if not, something on the low-voltage side is drawing too much current.

Comment: The loaded primary current of a 150VA transformer is 1.25A at 120V.  (Not that the PS necessarily needs all 150 VA.) The resistors [maybe?] can dissipate 2W total.  if (1.25A)²×R=2W, then R=1.28Ω (for both), and each would be in the neighborhood of 640mΩ.  Maybe the silver band is the 1/100 multiplier (not tolerance- the tolerance band burned off), and they really did fail to a similar value?

Comment: @HanyHowie. 10% resistors tend only to be made in the E12 range, which jumps straight from 2k7 to 3k3. You don't get 3k0 until you step up to 5% tolerance (gold band). Hence a silver band eliminates that possibility.

Comment: What is the make and model of the audio amplifier? Could it be that they used resistors instead of a correctly-rated transformer? It would be wasteful to use resistors to reduce the voltage across a transformer, so perhaps the schematic in the question needs to be checked.

Comment: This is a Paradigm PS-1200 subwoofer from 1999. I have tried to contact the company for information (even a replacement board) but they have not responded. It appears to be well-designed, but I don't know the purpose of these resistors.

Comment: @JYelton From [Auto power on problem with Paradigm PS1000](https://www.avforums.com/threads/auto-power-on-problem-with-paradigm-ps1000.853831/), I guess that two 3 W 4K7 resistors might fix it. Use your own judgement as to the resistance value; slightly-higher-power rated components will have a very small effect on the cost, just make sure there is a few mm of gap between the resistor and the surface of the PCB to aid in heat dissipation. I am not a qualified electrical engineer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They look like they could be Orange, Black, Red, Gold to me - 3k.

This [page](https://www.avforums.com/threads/paradigm-ps-1200a-subwoofer-issue.1997259/) also backs this up where someone has the exact same problem -

The last comment there was - “I contacted Paradigm and the tech told the resistor values: 3K ohms 2Watt for R90 & R91. Some model versions might be different.”

On this [page](https://www.stereo.net.au/forums/uploads/monthly_07_2014/post-111065-0-24912000-1404609763.jpg) you can see a photo of the board with the two resistors on -

[image]

[Here](https://www.avforums.com/threads/auto-power-on-problem-with-paradigm-ps1000.853831/page-2) is what I believe the schematic should look like.  You can see the 3k resistors on there.  Probably used for standby power mode.
[image]

Comment: Why would you place two 3k resistors in series with a fuse? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Also the resistors on your pic appear to be orange, blue, violet, gold (? it's hard to see) It ain't 3k that's for sure.

Comment: @Lundin The OP has reverse engineered the board, maybe they have made a mistake.

Comment: @Lundin I have just checked on a few different monitors and they all look like Orange, Black, Red, Gold to me.  Admittedly they are not the clearest of photos.

Comment: @HandyHowie After reviewing your answer and probing the board a bit more I have indeed discovered that the TRIAC is set up in parallel with the resistors as shown on the schematic you found. Now it makes a lot more sense, as the TRIAC once latched will provide the connection from mains to the transformer instead of the resistors alone.

Comment: They are probably for a soft-start at power-on.

Comment: @KevinWhite I thought for supplying the standby mode power supply.

Comment: @HandyHowie If 2 W resistors failed, would you suggest that their replacements be rated at 3 W, or maybe 5 W if they will physically fit? I see from the photo that they have been installed close to the PCB: would a few millimetres of stand-off be a good idea to aid heat dissipation, and maybe angled to give a bit more distance to the electrolytic caps?

Comment: It would make sense to do what you suggest to keep the new ones as cool as possible. If higher power ones will fit you may as well use them.

Answer (score 4):

Those might be 0.1 ohm (brown, black, gold) and have been discolored by heat over time. If they're reading 2.8K then they've definitely failed.

More about color codes here: https://www.petervis.com/electronics/Standard_Resistor_Values/0R1.html

MORE/REVISIT:

Or, they could be 3.0k (orange, black, red). That makes more sense, given that they haven't failed open and read about that value. Given @HandyHowie 's answer, backed up with a photo, that seems to be your huckleberry. So, dear reader, if you voted for this answer, unvote and vote for that one.

Comment: What would be the purpose of two 0.1 ohm resistors in series with the primary of a transformer? There is already a fuse in the circuit.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - Two components such as these resistors in series (also sometimes parallel combinations are used) is often done to spread out the overall power dissipation across multiple components. Resistor values adjusted according to design requirements. If a design wants a net 2.2 ohm resistor then two 1.1 ohm resistors can be used in series.

Comment: 3.0k? Might be (orange->brown, red-> burnt away). It's a bit like that blue/black or white/gold dress, isn't it?